# Unable to add a event handler in silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, visual-studio-2010

I position a button as "Press to see Eifel"

`<button type="button" id="Eifel">Eifel</button><br />`

And in the MainPage I try to add an event handler for this button but it fails

```
HtmlElement htmlEl = htmlDoc.GetElementById("Eifel");
htmlEl.AttachEvent("onclick", new EventHandler<HtmlEventArgs>(onClickEifel));
```

The editor keeps underlining the above EventHandler red with message that "Sorry no overload matches for Eventhandler.....found".

This is real question, not homework. I am learning the basics and couldn't find an answer except stackoverflow.

Thank you

Comment: Please post the actual error message. The version you have above is slightly garbled and doesn't give us a lot to go on.

Comment: It's on my mind now.:-) _error CS0123: No overload for 'onClickConvert' matches delegate 'System.EventHandler'_ I will go out take a exercise walk to the temple (I cant run anymore,its crytally clear :-D), later will post back to you if you have any reply. Thanks in advance.

Comment: please post the method signature for `onClickEifel` ..

Answer (score 1):

Your method `onClickEifel` (or `onClickConvert`) has to have a signature that matches the [EventHandler<TEventArgs>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x.aspx) delegate, so in your case:

```
private void onClickEifel(object sender, HtmlEventArgs e) 
{ 
   // your code
}
```

Is that the case? Some reading on `Delegates` if you require it:

[Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173171.aspx)
[Using Delegates (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173172.aspx)